# Drools: Using 'or' in criterium for building a list

Tags: drools

I am in a situation where I need to build a list of objects that comply to *the disjunction ('or') of two criteria*. These criteria themselves are atomic to me, I can't change them.

I can't use `from collect` because it does not allow multiple patterns. `accumulate` does, but it does not allow anything that has -or simplifies to- a disjunction in its condition part.

For example, I can do:

```
$myList: ArrayList() from accumulate (
    (and
        $book: Book()
        <Constraint A>
        <Constraint B>
    );
    collectList($book)
)
```

These constraints can be other patterns or eval statements that in some way apply to $book and/or its properties. What I however *want* to do, but can **not** do:

```
$myList: ArrayList() from accumulate (
    (and
        $book: Book()
        (
            <Constraint A>
            or
            <Constraint B>
        )
    );
    collectList($book)
)
```

Another way to go about this is to bring the disjunction outside of the `accumulate` clause, e.g.:

```
$listA: ArrayList() from accumulate (
    (and
        $book: Book()
        <Constraint A>
    );
    collectList($book)
)
$listB: ArrayList() from accumulate (
    (and
        $book: Book()
        <Constraint A>
    );
    collectList($book)
)
$myList: <somehow concatenate lists listA and listB>
```

For this I would need to concatenate two lists, and I haven't found that to be possible so far. I'm kinda stuck...

Comment: You might want to use a query instead?

Comment: Can I use a query in a rule? (I've looked but couldn't find an example in the documentation that mentions this) -- EDIT: doh! You made me look again and now I've found it. It was just one of the many possibly dead end roads to me before. I'll try this first now.

Comment: Yes you can (and also from outside using the kie api, which is perhaps what you need?) Have a look here https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.4.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#QuerySection

Comment: I need it in the LHS, and I need to do aggregation on the result list, e.g. take the sum, the average, min, max, .., but also check containment. Hence I really need a list, and I need it inside the LHS. But I think I've pulled it off! It certainly looks like it, though I'm not a jedi tester. I'll post it as an answer here.

Comment: You can use queries in the LHS (in fact they make little sense in the RHS)

Answer (score 0):

So with help of @raphaëλ, this is a working solution now:

```
query listBuilder(Book book)
    (or
        <ConstraintA>
        <ConstraintB>
    )
end

rule "some rule using a list"
    when
        ...
        accumulate (
            (and
                $book: Book()
                listBuilder($book;)
            );
            $myList: collectList($book)
        )
        ...
end
```

`$myList` is now the list that I was looking to build, and because it is still built with `accumulate`, I can even use all of `accumulate`'s powerful aggregation functions.